# Android: How to close database from custom list adapter

Tags: android, listadapter

How/where can you close a database connection from within a custom list adapter?

I have to perform a database look-up from within a custom list adapter.  This means that I have to open the database within the adapter.  When I change the originating activity to another, I receive a "DatabaseObjectNotClosedException".  I tried all the lifecycle events and none get called within the custom adapter.

onDestroy/onStop and everything else never gets called.

Some Code

```
public class myAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter 
{
    private db      mDbHelper;

    private Cursor      c;
    private Context     context;

    public myAdapter(Context context, int layout, 
            Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to )
    {

    super(context, layout, c, from, to );

        this.c = c;
        this.context = context;

        mDbHelper   = new db    ( context );
        mDbHelper.open();

    }

    public View getView(final int pos, View inView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = inView;

        if ( v == null )
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row, parent, false);
        }


    this.c.moveToPosition(pos);

    String n = this.c.getString( this.c.getColumnIndex("name" ));
    String c = this.c.getString( this.c.getColumnIndex("cat"  ));

    int vCAT_COLOR[] = mDbHelper.dbio_getCatColors( loc_cat );

    // dispay data here in correct color
    }

    public void onDestroy() { Log.w("TAG", "onDestroy" ); mDbHelper.close(); }
    public void onStop()()  { Log.w("TAG", "onStop"    ); mDbHelper.close(); }
}
```

Comment: show us some of what you tried

Comment: Can you post some code ?